# RegEx match not working

Tags: javascript, regex

So what I want to match is anything that ends with ".ProjectName" so I wrote a small test case. I purposely created the pattern using RegExp because in the real case scenario I will be using a variable as part of the reg ex pattern. I'm not sure if my pattern is not correct (90% sure it correct), or if I am misusing the match function (70% sure I am suing it right). The blow code returns me something when the second case notMatchName should not return me anything

```
var inputName = "ProjectName";
var matchName = "userInput_Heading.Heading.ProjectName";
var notMatchName = "userInput_Heading.Heading.Date";
var reg = new RegExp(".*[." + inputName + "]");
console.log(reg);
console.log(matchName.match(reg));
console.log(matchName.match(reg)[0]);
console.log(notMatchName.match(reg));
console.log(notMatchName.match(reg)[0]);
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZb6s/1/) to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var reg = new RegExp(".*\." + inputName);
```

The square brackets mean: one character, which is one of those within the brackets. But you want several characzters, first a dot, then the first character of `inputName`, etc.

Comment: @FrankPI Slap me silly and call me Uncle willy that was stupid of me. Ugh LOL.

Answer (score 1):

your regular expression should be `.*\.projectName`

if you rewrite your statement it will be

```
var reg = new RegExp(".*\." + inputName)
```